# Disable offset in axis labelling in PyPlot

Tags: matplotlib, julia

How can you achieve this python code in Julia?

```
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
```

I've tried the following but ':get_major_formatter' is not found

```
ax[:get_yaxis][:get_major_formatter][:set_useOffset](false)
```

And with the following, ':set_useOffset' isn't found

```
ax[:yaxis][:get_major_formatter][:set_useOffset](false)
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct implementation found [here](https://github.com/stevengj/PyPlot.jl/issues/64)

```
ax[:get_yaxis]()[:get_major_formatter]()[:set_useOffset](false)
```